# Making database schema changes using Microsoft Sync framework without losing any tracking table data

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I am using Microsoft Synch Service Framework 4.0 for synching Sql server Database tables with SqlLite Database on the Ipad side.

Before making any Database schema changes in the Sql Server Database, We have to Deprovision the database tables. ALso after making the schema changes, we ReProvision the tables.
Now in this process, the tracking tables( i.e. the Synching information) gets deleted.

I want the tracking table information to be restored after Reprovisioning.
How can this be done? Is it possible to make DB changes without Deprovisioning.

e.g, the application is in Version 2.0, The synching is working fine. Now in the next version 3.0, i want to make some DB changes. SO, in the process of Deprovisioning-Provisioning, the tracking info. gets deleted. So all the tracking information from the previous version is lost. I do not want to loose the tracking info. How can i restore this tracking information from the previous version.

I believe we will have to write a custom code or trigger to store the tracking information before Deprovisioning. Could anyone suggest a suitable method OR provide some useful links regarding this issue.

Answer (score 4):

the provisioning process should automatically populate the tracking table for you. you don't have to copy and reload them yourself.

now if you think the tracking table is where the framework stores what was previously synched, the answer is no.

the tracking table simply stores what was inserted/updated/deleted. it's used for change enumeration. the information on what was previously synched is stored in the scope_info table.

when you deprovision, you wipe out this sync metadata. when you synch, its like the two replicas has never synched before. thus you will encounter conflicts as the framework tries to apply rows that already exists on the destination.

you can find information here on how to "hack" the sync fx created objects to effect some types of schema changes.

[Modifying Sync Framework Scope Definition – Part 1 – Introduction](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/modifying-sync-framework-scope-definition-part-1-introduction/)

[Modifying Sync Framework Scope Definition – Part 2 – Workarounds](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/modifying-sync-framework-scope-definition-part-2-workarounds/)

[Modifying Sync Framework Scope Definition – Part 3 – Workarounds – Adding/Removing Columns](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/modifying-sync-framework-scope-definition-part-3-workarounds-addingremoving-columns/)

[Modifying Sync Framework Scope Definition – Part 4 – Workarounds – Adding a Table to an existing scope](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/04/28/modifying-sync-framework-scope-definition-part-4-workarounds-adding-a-table-to-an-existing-scope/)

Comment: Thank you June.. That means I will have to customize some of the stored procedures and triggers. ( as mentioned in your links). So whenever I need to make any DB schema changes, I can directly do them without Deprovisioning. That way, sync metadata won't get erased.

Comment: yes, but take note that you will have to update the tracking tables if you change PKs or add/removed filters. since you're using the Sync Fx Toolkit, you will have to update the entities you have in code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say I have one table "User" that I want to synch.
A tracking table will be created "User_tracking" and some synch information will be present in it after synching.

WHen I make any DB changes, this Tracking table "User_tracking" will be deleted AND the tracking info. will be lost during the Deprovisioning- Provisioning process.

My workaround:
Before Deprovisioning, I will write a script to copy all the "User_tracking" data into another temporary table "User_tracking_1". so all the existing tracking info will be stored in "User_tracking_1". WHen I reprovision the table, a new trackin table "User_Tracking" will be created.
After Reprovisioning, I will copy the data from table "User_tracking_1" to "User_Tracking" and then delete the contents from table "User_Tracking_1".
    UserTracking info will be restored.

Is this the right approach...