# Sync framework with encryption

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssl, microsoft-sync-framework, syncfx

I am using Sync framework default database provider to synchronization (Sync framework 2.1). Can anyone please give me bit explanation how data transfer between client and server with sync framework? Are there any security threat with this Synchronizing? Can we use encryption with default database provider?

I read the following article,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887608.aspx

> From a synchronization perspective, Sync Framework supports the
>   ability to encrypt data as it travels between databases. On the
>   corporate side, SQL Server 2008 as well as existing IIS security can
>   be leveraged for user authentication as users exchange data.

we are using the default sync provider. Can we use default database provider to synchronize over the HTTPS or SSL? Basically what I need to know is, can someone see the data transferring between client to server?

Please give me your answer.

Regards,

Comment: Hi I used this technology and made a windows service to run the synchronization because we had two networks each one with different vpn. From my experience I can say that the synchronization use a combination of triggers, history tables and store procedures. Changes in the schema are possible but you have to update the store procedures and the triggers for that. You don't have a wizard to make this changes. And the re provision process can be hard.

Try other options before take your final decision of using this technology when Microsoft begun with Azure they left this effort behind.

Comment: Can anyone please give some idea?

Comment: If you use SSL this protect the data transportation. And your sql server security credentials is enough for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

This post help me when I was using this technology

[Making database schema changes using Microsoft Sync framework without losing any tracking table data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192728/making-database-schema-changes-using-microsoft-sync-framework-without-losing-any)

Here you can find two articles with information

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_21acb3mbRQV3Mxdm5TeVVTcEU&usp=sharing

Hi if your are using ssl its enough for encryption purpuse

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Juan, Thank you for your feedback. Those are very helpful. Actually I have successfully implemented this Sync framework with default database provider within my application. Recently my client asked the data security with synchronizing between the client and the server. Because of that, I need to know whether we can implement  the encryption with default database provider or not.

Answer (score 0):

Sync Framework OOTB doesn't encrypt data over the wire.

if you're synching over HTTP, then you can enable SSL to encrypt the traffic.

you can also enable TDS encryption on the SQL Connection.